# Is it possible for an object to have one value when accessed directly and also nested object inside?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it's possible in Javascript for an object property to have the following behaviour:

```
console.log(obj); // output 'Something'
console.log(obj.prop_a); // output 'A'
```

And also

```
var a = obj; // a === 'Something'
var b = obj.prop_a; /// b === 'A'
```

The object kind of have two versions, one when you access it directly, and one when you access one of it's children props

Thanks

Comment: Is there some specific use case here or just wondering?

Comment: @Jon Both. I have an object that I can't change it's value when accessed directly but i'd like to glue more information to it when passed further

Comment: So just add a property to it. Where's the problem? `obj.prop_a = "A"`.

Comment: @Jon because then when accessing just `obj`, it will return `{ "prop_a": "A" }` and I would like to return a different value

Comment: Do you really need to put the extra info on the object? jQuery allows you to use `.data` to put arbitrary amounts of info on an object, but it stores it in a separate container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can override `toString()` method:

```
obj.toString = function() {
    return "Something";
}
```

Comment: That is nice, haven't thought of it. Not sure I always want to print the value though

Comment: I;m not sure how this will work w/ `console` in different browsers different behaviour, but in alert it will work. However look at jsFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/6ccY2/

Comment: It's for `node.js` so it's running ES5 under the hood

Comment: I was looking for a more general solution actually, not just for printing the value of `obj`. so for example if I did `var a = obj` then a will equal to `Something` and I could still access `a.prop_a`. I guess it's not possible.

Comment: @Michael I guess not too

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to work in the browser, you would have to hook the console, as well as override the toString method of the object.

```
You could hook the browser console, and redefine it afterwards:

var obj = {
  prop_a: "A",
  toString: function() {
    return "Something";
  }
};

var origConsole = console;

console = {
  log: function(data) {
    if (typeof data === "object") {
        origConsole.log(data.toString());
    } else {
        origConsole.log(data);
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```